# How can I find an iOS app I had installed once but since deleted?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

[image]

i had this app on my old phone and when i got a new phone i could never find the name of it. I thought it was called "InstaFollowers" but i guess not. This app specifically has a calender where everyday for 30 days is something different and you get to spin a wheel and everything! If anyone knows what app this is let me know!

Answer (score 3):

If your old phone and new phone are both iPhones, then all you need to do is check the purchase history under your Apple ID to re-download it.

To do this:

- Launch the App Store app on your iPhone
- Tap on Updates
- Tap on Purchased

You will now be able to access your purchase history and, should even be able to filter by the *Not on This iPhone* tab.

If you can't find the app in your history, then it's possible that it's no longer available on the App Store. If that's the case, you may be able to re-install it from iTunes on your computer, especially if you have Time Machine backups (assuming you're on a Mac).